# Get first value as NULL in SELECT query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
Select Col1 from tbl1 where Col2= 'abc';
```

The result will be:

```
Col1
-----
David  
Harman  
Joe
```

I want to add NULL in my result set and I don't have any entry in my Col1 which is NULL. So result should be:

```
Col1  
-----
NULL  
David  
Harman  
Joe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use union.

```
Select Col1 from tbl1 where Col2= 'abc' Union select null as Col1 from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT NULL AS Col1 
UNION ALL
Select Col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE Col2= 'abc';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `php` 
you just retrieve from database and display by following format

```
foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
    if($v->name=='')
          echo "NULL";
     else
          echo $v->name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Case statement like this :

```
Select distinct (Case when col2='abc' then col_1 else null end)Col_1
from 
Your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't guarantee a sort order unless you specify it.  If you want a null first (and guarantee this result), you'd do something like this:

```
select * from (
    select 'x' as col1 from dual
    union all
    select null as col1 from dual
)
order by col1 nulls first
```